# defaultProxy.useDefaultCredentials in WCF client programmatically

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, system.net

What code I should write to get same behavior as I set in config file

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"></defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for me:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```